# New examples for Black Speech in Rings of Power

Tags: tolkien-black-speech

In the latest episodes of *[The Rings of Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings:_The_Rings_of_Power)*, several orcs say something in Black Speech, which is not translated in the subtitles. I had a brief look on the web, but cannot find anything about the meaning of these phrases.

Has anybody come across an analysis of that, and whether/how it fits in with previous attempts at reconstructing Black Speech from known fragments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My lame attempt at analyzing Black Speech in Amazon's show: https://un4givenorc.blogspot.com/2023/07/orcish-black-speech-in-amazons-rings-of.html
Would be glad, if anyone corrects misheard phrases or suggest other Elvish etymologies.

**EDIT:** Neo Black Speech for Amazon's show is obviously not based on any previous attempts. But whoever was responsible for it, seems to have an approach similar to Shadowlandian: some words are derived from other languages invented by J.R.R. Tolkien. Neo-BS in ROP has a higher degree of agglutination.

Some phrases that have clear meaning:

- Nampat! - wasn't translated in English, but official Russian    subtitles and some media articles have a translation: "Death!", but the correct one would probably be "Die!".
- Nampak uglursha - in the context probably some equivalent of "Rest    in peace", "nampat" (see above) seems has meaning "die"; other    options include: Gnomish "nam-" (to withdraw, retire); "ak" is probably some grammatical or objective clitic pronoun; "uglur" may be derived from Adunaic "aglar" (glory), however "ugl-" in other Neo-BS dialects means "to frighten, scare"; "-sha" is probably postposition "with", used as preposition in Orc-curse
- Izmûmbogh - I smell him! - my guess was "I can feel (him)" < Gnomish "ist-" (feeling, sense), "og-" (can, be able / adjective suffix / agental suffix); Sindarin "im" (I, 1st person singular pronoun)
- Kishdibatoth! - Search it! < Quenya "ces(ta)" (to search for,
  examine); "ib" - probably some grammatical suffix; "-at" BS infinitive/gerund/participle suffix expressing intention or purpose; "oth" < Sindarin "eth" (any 3rd person pronoun) or "ed" (it), could be also from early Noldorin "os" (around)

Comment: The quoted web page may go away, leaving this answer quite stale. Could you add the content from that web page to the answer?

Comment: Most translations are purely speculative, so I will not quote everything here, at least until 1st season ends.